# Why is my CSS margin applying to the wrong spot?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Emiel Zuurbier has already given a useful response and i have re done all my code and no longer have this issue

The margin-top in `.base` for the CSS is applying the margin-top to the very top of the screen and I don't know what's causing the problem.

Using `float` is what caused the problem, but I don't know any other way to get the divs to align

```js
play = document.getElementById("play");
game = document.getElementById("game");
work = document.getElementById("work");
stats = document.getElementById("stats");
v1 = document.getElementById("value1");
a1 = document.getElementById("amt1");
var base = {
  lines: 0,
  value: 0,
  text1: "lines of code: ",
  text2: "Value: $"
}
var stat = {
  money: 0,
  level: 0,
  exp: 0,
  need: 0
}
game.style.display = 'none';
play.addEventListener("click", () => {
  play.style.display = 'none';
  game.style.display = '';
});
work.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (work.innerHTML == "work") {
    work.innerHTML = "stop";
    t1 = setInterval(BW, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(t1);
    work.innerHTML = "work";
  }
});

function BW() {
  base.lines = Math.max(base.lines + 1, 0);
  base.value = Math.max(base.lines * 5, 0);
  a1.innerHTML = base.text1 + base.lines;
  v1.innerHTML = base.text2 + base.value;
}

function update() {
  stats.innerHTML = "Money: " + stat.money + "   " + stat.exp + " / " + stat.exp + "   " + stat.level;
}
upd = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: #5A5A5A;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.title {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.pb {
  text-align: center;
}

.play {
  background: gray;
  width: 20%;
  height: 4%;
}

.game {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.side {
  background: gray;
  float: left;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 20%
}

.screen {
  background: #6A6A6A;
  float: right;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 75%;
}

.stats {
  width: 58vmax;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}

.select {
  font-size: 3vmax;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: #6A6A6A;
  height: 15%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.select:hover {
  background: #5A5A5A;
}

.amt1 {
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}

.base {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 15vmax;
  height: 15vmax;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.t1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}

.value1 {
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}

.wrk {
  height: 3vmax;
  width: 6vmax;
  margin-top: 0.2vmax;
  background: #6A6A6A;
  font-size: 2vmax;
}

.wrk:hover {
  background: #5A5A5A;
}

.stuff {
  width: 14.8vmax;
  height: 31.8vmax;
  background: red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <h1 class="title">GAME</h1>
  <div class="pb" id="p">
    <button class="play" id="play">play</button>
  </div>
  <div class="game" id="game">
    <div class="side">
      <button class="select">Work</button>
      <button class="select">Workers</button>
      <button class="select">Home</button>
      <button class="select">name</button>
      <button class="select">name</button>
    </div>
    <div class="screen">
      <div class="work">
        <div class="stats" id="stats">stats</div>
        <div class="stuff" id="stuff"></div>
        <div class="base">
          <div class="t1">develop base</div>
          <div class="amt1" id="amt1">lines of code: 0</div>
          <div class="value1" id="value1">value: $0</div>
          <button class="wrk" id="work">work</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="workers">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I was expecting the margin to be applied above the box and not above the stats

Comment: How do you know that it is the margin from `.base` that is showing at the top of the page? The best way to tell is to use the built in developer tools (F12) in your browser and look at the box model diagram.

Comment: i know that the margin is from .base because when i remove it the margin that is not where it should be is removed

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in the page's top margin when `.base` is removed.   (Meanwhile, you said `float` caused the issue, but which `float`?  There isn't one on `.base`)

Comment: I'd recommend that you look into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Floats is what we used when these tools weren't around, but as you can see, floats aren't easy, and above all not meant for creating complex layouts.

Comment: change your comment to an answer

Answer (score 0):

As I look through the markup, it seems like all the positioning is done by margins. You may consider transitioning to [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It would eliminate many similar issues in the future. It is going to allow positining elements in a way they are aware(kind of) of each other.

Onto the solution:
The issue with the margin-top in the `.base` class is caused by the float property being applied to the `.side` and `.screen` divs. When an element is floated, it is taken out of the normal document flow, which can affect the positioning of other elements.

To achieve the desired layout without using float, you can use CSS Flexbox. Here's how you can modify your code:

1.Remove the float property from the `.side` and `.screen` classes.

2.Add a container div around the .side and .screen divs and give it a class, for example, `.container`.

3.Apply Flexbox properties to the .container class.